# Compare two sheet columns and copy data to first Sheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to find out the formula for matching `CODE 1` between Sheet1 and Sheet2, then, copy 'Original','Lost' and insert 'Total 2019 Order' columns into Sheet 1 by corresponding `CODE 1`,

The google sheet is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SvMVC0P6eWcmaULEolu0zTr2wv6zlFl9-ttkgaxXcX8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, Sheet2!B2:I, {8, 5}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sly1awobUOzeOyDhskb0L19F-j5UpRjrQc-vqPmdw1E/edit#gid=0https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sly1awobUOzeOyDhskb0L19F-j5UpRjrQc-vqPmdw1E/edit#gid=0https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sly1awobUOzeOyDhskb0L19F-j5UpRjrQc-vqPmdw1E/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Actually, I am looking for doing this by Google Script click to finish the work, not formula.. Sheet two "2019" or more years, need to insert into Sheet 1 automatically by running google script. please advise.