# How to replace all cells in a google sheet by its translation when I already have 2 columns of the word in both languages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet filled with League of Legends champions names in Korean.
I have another sheet with 2 columns, where I have the name in Korean in the first column and the name in English in the other one.

I want to replace all the Korean names in the first sheet by its equivalent in English. It sounds like a LOOKUP for each cell but I don't know how I can automate that.

Example Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LAflwQtkqCymqh0khimIQkbgSGaPANE-zg_H2hoU7t8/edit?usp=sharing

I have the cells in Korean in the first sheet called *Example* and in the second sheet *Reference*, I have 2 columns (Korean & English).

Comment: What do you mean by a sheet and if it an excel sheet - what it has to do with javascript? 

In javascript terms - if you have the first sheet as a string or array of strings and the second one is an object where the key is Korean name and value is English name, you can simply call the `replace` function which will find matches in a string of the key and replace with the proper value.

Comment: I'm working on google sheets and I put javascript as it's the language used by the Google Sheets' script editor tool.

Comment: Edited the hashtags for you. There is another tag for google apps script specifically. Sadly I am not familiar with it to give you more specific advice, but it might be worth checking what native `replace` function does and if it might be of any use to you

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: look into VLOOKUP - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60164380/5632629

Comment: Added an example in the original post! Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi there @Hajin! I can't access the example spreadsheet. Please, make it public (*share with anyone*) so we all can study it to help you better.

Comment: oh right! Done, thanks @Jacques-GuzelHeron

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question I wrote a code that fulfills your expectations. This is the code in question:

```js
function koreanTranslator() {
  var spreadsheetID = "{SPREADSHEET ID}";
  var koreanSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID).getSheetByName(
    "Example");
  var koreanCells = koreanSheet.getRange(1, 1, koreanSheet.getLastRow(),
    koreanSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var equivalencesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID).getSheetByName(
    "Reference");
  var equivalencesCells = equivalencesSheet.getRange(2, 1, equivalencesSheet
    .getLastRow(),
    2).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < koreanCells.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < koreanCells[0].length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < equivalencesCells.length; k++) {
        if (koreanCells[i][j] == equivalencesCells[k][0]) {
          koreanSheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).setValue(equivalencesCells[k][1]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code will first open the spreadsheet with [`.openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid), continuing by opening both sheets with [`.getSheetByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename). After that, it will read both tables with [`.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet.html#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) (calculating the size of the table with [`.getLastColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) and [`.getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow), so you can use bigger or shorter tables without changing the code) and [`.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).

Finally, the code will iterate by each cell in the *korean sheet* and compare it with the *dictionary sheet*; and if it finds a coincidence it will update the *korean sheet* with [`.setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues). Please, don't hesitate to comment on my answer for further help or more clarification.

Comment: I get an error line 3 and koreanSheet is undefined when I debug. (And all the other var like koreanCells, equivalencesCells etc. Any idea why?